# Migrate from remote back to local

Tags: localhost, local-installation

A few years ago I developed my personal portfolio locally on my previous laptop, and then uploaded it to my web hosting.
Now I would like to download on my new computer the latest version of the website, so I can continue to develop and improve the front-end part with the same tools I used in the past (Gulp for minyfing css and js and other tools like that).

Unfortunately it is not working. This is what I have done so far:

1. From my hosting I have downloaded the new DDBB from phpAdmin, and uploaded it to Mamp's phpAdmin (name of the new DDBB: portfolio).
2. From the hosting I have downloaded the complete folder of the website and put it in the htdocs directory of Mamp
3. I start the Mamp server
4. I modify the options table of the new DDBB in Mamp as follows:
   Siteurl: localhost/folder
   Home: localhost/folder
5. I modify the wp-config.php file as follows:

   // ** ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** // //
   /** The name of the database for WordPress */
   define('DB_NAME', 'portfolio');
   /** MySQL database username */
   define('DB_USER', 'root');
   /** MySQL database password */
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
   /** MySQL hostname */
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   /** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
   /** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
   define('DB_COLLATE', '');
6. When I go to localhost/folder/wp-admin/ in browser, it looks like a mess, like a plain html of the main Wordpress admin page.

What am I missing?

More info: i tried to install a new Wordpress blog, and it seems to work fine, so Mamp should not be the problem. I'm using ports 80 & 3306 in Mamp confioguration, so I don't have to type :8888 in the url to access the local server.

---

For all those who are facing my same problem, I have found the solution in this [guide](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-live-wordpress-site-to-local-server/). In my case with the 2nd method.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: often it's not enough to change the URL like that as it can be found in many more places in the database. You might also have done things like hardcode the URL in the PHP, or stored the URLs of images in the database as strings instead of using attachment IDs. All of those need to be changed too via a search replace. There are lots of tools inside and outside the WordPress ecosystem, though WP CLI has a command for it if you want a tool that's officially part of the WP project

Comment: Yes. `wp search-replace <old-base-url> <new-base-url>` is your friend here.

Comment: So, it is just a URLs problem?